# Best way to connect tables in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm fairly new to php and coding in general. I have an assignment to make a student and lecturer appointment system.

This system involves a timetable where lecturers can update if they are available or not, and students can book appointments based on this timetable. Generally, I know how to do simple CRUD in php, but I'm a bit muddled over how to connect everything together(which is the only thing keeping me from actually completing this assignment),  so I'm hoping you have some suggestions to help me. I've been looking around but couldn't find anything that helped.

For now, I have a `student_info` table which has `id, f_name, l_name, faculty, id_num` . This is where I'm stuck. How can I add the subjects that the student enrolled in, and then connect those subjects to the lecturer in charge and the timetable?

Should I extend the `student_info` table by adding `subject1, subject2 and so on`? Or should I create a new table for each student and what subjects they have enrolled in? Should the `lect_info` table be the same as `student_info` table?

Also, for the timetable for each subject, how can I do that in mysql so that I can display the timetable as well as the lecturer who is in charge?

[Schedule page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opuff.jpg)

This screenshot is how the page would look like, just in case it can give a better view of what I'm trying to run. Basically, just by clicking the link to this page, I want it to display the subject, subject code, timetable(as in, when the lecturer is free or busy) and lecturer's name from the mysql database.

I hope this question isn't too confusing. If anyone has any ideas of suggestions, please share them! It would help me a lot in this assignment!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read & learn about the [bridge table](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?125,126840,126840)

Comment: you can simply create a new table subject(#idstudent, subject) maybe you can add time to this table, or you can make a third table subject(id, subject) and link(#idsubject, #idstudent).  (# are foreign key)

Comment: Bridge tables did help. Thank you!